# C++11: constexpr constructor performance

Tags: c++11

I got little confused with constepxt ctors..

Does the following is as just as fast (or faster)

```
while(true)
{
   constexpr std::chrono::hours one_hour(1);
   ..
}
```

than (creating only one instance):

```
while(true)
{
   static constexpr std::chrono::hours one_hour(1);
   ..
}
```

In other words, Does constexpr ctor means no runtime overhead whatsoever?

Comment: Generate the assembly code for both alternatives, both unoptimized and optimized, and check for differences. I'll bet that for at least the optimized code there won't be any difference.

Comment: Right. But I am insterested in the concept. Does constexpr ctor means no runtime overhead what-so ever?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does constexpr ctor means no runtime overhead whatsoever?

When in doubt, you can always check; for example:

```
#include <chrono>

template <long Long>
class dummy { };

int main() {

  constexpr std::chrono::hours one_hour(1);

  dummy<one_hour.count()> d; 
}
```

The fact that it compiles means that `one_hour` **is a compile time constant** and as such, has no runtime overhead whatsoever.

Comment: _is a compile time constant and as such, has no runtime overhead whatsoever_ - not really. It has to exist in application, just like a value initialized at run-time. `constexpr` basically says that the value is available at compile time as a constant.

Comment: *"It has to exist in application"* Not necessarily. If the compiler is able verify that you never take the address of it, I believe it can replace all occurrences of `one_hour` as if it had come from a macro, something like `#define one_hour 1`. It certainly does that on my machine; I looked at the assembly.

Comment: You are right. _"It has to exist in application"_ - I mean either exist as on object (if the address is taken) or its value hard-coded in the machine code (if it is ever used).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Agreed. But how could you possibly do better than that? :) In my opinion that means no *overhead*. If you think this wording is confusing or erroneous, please suggest a better one.

Comment: As I mentioned that `std::chrono` durations and time points are mere wrappers for an integer, there may be little difference in using a hard-coded integer value or a value known at run-time only. When performing arithmetic operations with it the CPU will still have to load that in a register. However, I agree with you, that some operations can be done more efficiently if the value is known at compile time, e.g. if it is power of 2 then all multiplications/divisions can be converted to cheaper register shifts.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `constexpr` here won't make much difference because `std::chrono` durations and time points contain only a single integer member. In other words. the performance of initialization is the same as of `int`.